# How to tail a remote Linux server log file to a local Windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, tail

I have an app that's running on a Linux server, and it produces log files on that server. I personally use a Windows machine and wonder if there's any way to tail the log file on the remote Linux server, and stream it to a file on my Windows machine hard disk?

I know there are some 3rd party web sites/software but I'm curious if there are any native ways of doing this

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about sharing the file using samba and just tailing it via the share

Answer (score 0):

[Logstash](http://logstash.net/) not only transfers your file, but also can parse your logfields and display it on a nice UI [Kibana 3](http://demo.kibana.org/#/dashboard). Hope this helps. Moreover these tools are cross platform and run on Linux/Mac/Windows.